# Como apagar os registros de diversas tabelas pontuando as que não deverão ser apagadas no sql server 2014?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados

Gostaria de apagar todos os registros das tabelas do meu banco de dados, porém algumas tabelas não podem ser apagadas, aqui no meu caso por exemplo eu tenho uma média de 20 tabelas das quais 6 não podem ser apagado os registros. Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode recuperar o nome de todas as tabelas do banco e executar o comando delete.
exemplo:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)=''

SELECT @sql += ' DELETE FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.NAME) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.NAME) + '; '
FROM   sys.tables t
       JOIN sys.schemas s
         ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE  t.type = 'U' AND t.NAME NOT IN ('','','','')

Exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Observe a linha: `AND t.NAME NOT IN ('','','','')`
dentro das aspas simples você deve colocar os nome das tabelas que NÃO QUER DELETAR os dados.